# sending function value to another function yii model

Tags: php, yii

i am unable to send a value from another function to another function inside yii. Both functions is inside the same file, a Model inside yii. below is the code.

```
public function totalPointsValue($userId) {

    $value = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('sum(totalPoints) as pointsSum')
        ->from('fndn_UserTotal')
        ->where('userId =:id', array(':id'=>$userId))
        //->where('userId = ' . $userId)
        ->queryRow();

    $totalPoints = $value['pointsSum'];
}

public function checkEligable(){

            totalPointsValue($userId);
    error_log(print_r($totalPoints, true), 3, 'debug.log');

}
```

is it possible to send the value from totalPointsValue() to checkEligable() ?

Comment: You mean like `return $totalPoints;` from `totalPointsValue`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> ```
> public function totalPointsValue($userId) {
>       $value = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
>           ->select('sum(totalPoints) as pointsSum')
>           ->from('fndn_UserTotal')
>           ->where('userId =:id', array(':id'=>$userId))
>           //->where('userId = ' . $userId)
>           ->queryRow();
>       return $value['pointsSum'];
> }
>
> public function checkEligable(){
>         $totalPoints = $this->totalPointsValue($userId);
>         error_log(print_r($totalPoints, true), 3, 'debug.log');
> }
> ```

OR another variant of checkEligable:

> ```
> public function checkEligable(){
>         $totalPoints = self::model()->totalPointsValue($userId);
>         // OR $totalPoints = self::totalPointsValue($userId); 
>         // if totalPointsValue made static
>         error_log(print_r($totalPoints, true), 3, 'debug.log');
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
public function totalPointsValue($userId) 
{

    $value = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('sum(totalPoints) as pointsSum')
    ->from('fndn_UserTotal')
    ->where('userId =:id', array(':id'=>$userId))
    //->where('userId = ' . $userId)
    ->queryRow();

    $totalPoints = $value['pointsSum'];
}

public function checkEligable()
{

    ModelName::model()->totalPointsValue($userId);
    error_log(print_r($totalPoints, true), 3, 'debug.log');
}
```